# Getting around Meizu App Auto-Clean

Tags: android, android-service, battery, android-powermanager

I am having a problem where a Meizu phone is killing my Application, because of what seems to be a Meizu specific setting, where apps are killed after running and consuming power in the background for 3 minutes, after standby. Certain apps on the phone appear to be exempt from this by default. Does anyone know how I can make my app also be exempt from this auto-cleaning by default? Cheers